# R dplyr function putting mutate, top_frac and ifelse together

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

Im looking for ways to mutate a new column to assign the top and bottom 20% of values using dplyr.

Here is my code and it isnt working well for me.

```
DF1 <- DF %>%
  group_by(Timepoint) %>%
  filter (!is.na (log2_Concentration)) %>%
  arrange (desc(log2_Concentration)) %>%
  mutate (top_bottom=ifelse (log2_Concentration=top_frac(.2), "TOP20PERC",
          ifelse (log2_Concentration=top_frac(-.2), "BOTTOM20PERC", "MID")))

ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Timepoint, y=log2_Concentration,fill=Timepoint)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_jitter(size=1,position=position_jitter(0.2), aes(col=DF1$top_bottom)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "gray", "blue"), 
                      labels = c("TOP20PERC", "MID", "BOTTOM20PERC"))
```

My hope is to assign per timepoint, the top 20%, bottom 20% and the rest as MID so I can either color these points in my ggplot.

[[image: ggplot should look like that each timepoint will have top, mid and bottom[1]]

Thanks a lot gurus!

Comment: You appear to have changed the question topic from data munging to plotting.It's not clear whether you obtained that plot above from your data and don't like some aspect of it (OR?)  you are trying to emulate it. In either case it is a new question and you should accept the answer below to your earlier question and post a new question, BUT this time you should provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you can use `quantile` to get top and bottom 20%.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  filter(!is.na(log2_Concentration)) %>%
  group_by(Timepoint) %>%
  mutate(top_bottom= case_when(
           log2_Concentration > quantile(log2_Concentration, 0.8) ~"TOP20PERC", 
           log2_Concentration < quantile(log2_Concentration, 0.2) ~"BOTTOM20PERC", 
           TRUE ~ "MID"))
```

Comment: Hi, any suggestion to tease them per timepoint? When I was performing this, it doesnt seem so. What I hope is that for example at Timepoint 1, there will be a TOP20PERC, BOTTOM20PERC, MID, then similar at Timepoint 2 (grouped separately with TOP20PERC, Bottom and mid).

Comment: @user2533451 I think this works the same way. Try with `dplyr:: mutate` instead of just `mutate`. If it still doesn't work can you provide a reproducible example to debug this?

Comment: Hi Ronak, I have added the edits and my ggplot. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the plot doesn't clear why the answer doesn't work each `Timepoint` when we are actually grouping it by `Timepoint`. We would need a reproducible example to verify this. [See here on how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Add `dput(DF)` to your post.